# Convert XTS last business day of month index to last day of month

Tags: r, xts

I have a XTS object which has monthly data. However the date in the raw data is currently the last business day of the month, and I'd like it to be the last day of the month.

Is there a way to convert the XTS object so that the index has the last day of the month?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include in your question the output from `dput(head(data))` so we can help you a little eaiser? It would be nice to also include which column you want changed and an example of what you would like one or two values to look like

Comment: if `d` is a date vector then `as.Date(as.yearmon(d), frac = 1)` gives a vector of the  corresponding last day of the month.  These functions are in zoo which is automatically pulled in by xts so you won't need any additional packages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `bsts` package and the `LastDayInMonth()` function.

Say this is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:7, 
                 Date=as.Date(c("2007-01-01", "2007-01-31", "2008-02-01", "2008-02-29",
                                "2008-03-14", "2008-12-01", "2008-12-31")), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

You can get the new dates like this:

```
library(bsts)
df$New_Date <- LastDayInMonth(df$Date)
```

Does this do what you're after?